# How to send FCM notification in Android using Pubnub?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I am new to pubnub. I have to send FCM notification using Pubnub service. I am using this [link](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/mobile-gateway#about_the_pubnub_mobile_push_gateway).

I have created an FCM Server key and added on the Pubnub dashboard. Also Created device token on mobile. Then enablePushNotificationsOnChannel as follows

```
pubNotification.addPushNotificationsOnChannels()
                .pushType(PNPushType.GCM)
                .channels(Arrays.asList(CHANNEL_NAME_NOTIFICATION))
                .deviceId(deviceid)
                .async(new PNCallback<PNPushAddChannelResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(PNPushAddChannelResult result, PNStatus status) {
                // handle response.
            }
        });
```

Then publishing notification like this..

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("title","sandeep");
            jsonObject.put("name","sandeep");
            parent.put("data",jsonObject);
            object.put("pn_gcm",parent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        pubNotification.publish()
                .message(object)
                .channel(CHANNEL_NAME_NOTIFICATION)
                .async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                    }
                });
```

Then I added `onMessageReceived()` method to receive message, but not getting any notification. What will be the problem? Can any one help.

Comment: Where did you add `onMessageReceived()`? It must be a `GcmBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @CraigConover , I have added onMessageReceived() method in -public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{}

Comment: Are you sure that your message payload structure is correct? I'm not seeing anywhere in your code that you used `jsonObject` in the payload (`object`).

Comment: @AL Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
        payload.put("pn_gcm",object);  then added this payload in .message().I had tried this too..

Comment: Ow right. My bad on that one. Are you receiving any error response?

Comment: @AL. Log.e("publish", "" + status.getStatusCode()); is 200. but not getting notification.

Comment: Hi Sandeep. It's possible to receive an error with a 200 status code (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)). Could you also try and check the response message?

Comment: Review this [PubNub Mobile Push troubleshooting guide](https://www.google.com/search?q=pubnub+mobile+push+troubleshooting&oq=pubnub+mobile+&aqs=chrome.4.0j69i65j69i57j69i59l2j0.3423j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). If you continue to have issues, please provide all data you capture from this troubleshooting to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and add a link to this SO post so that we can answer back here when resolved.